# toArray function not working after ugrading atomikos version from 4 to 5

Tags: java, atomikos

I upgraded the atomikos version in my application from 4 to 5 after which toArray function started throwing "java.lang.ArrayStoreException" error. When i revert the version back to 4 it seems to be working fine. I am using toArray to convert a list of map to array of map.

Kindly help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Could you share some details? Is it a deploy time error or a runtime? I mean, when the exception appears? During application bootstrapping?

Please provide the relevant code snippets.

Sometimes when I got ArrayStoreException, the root cause was @Configuration naming collision. More precisely, I had two separate @Configuration annotated classes with the same fully qualified names. It was a strange exception and root cause.